# Expected Identifier in Symbol.for

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am building a react(v.16) component with webpack and babel.

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": ["env", "react"],
    "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread", 
                "transform-es3-member-expression-literals", 
                "transform-es3-property-literals",
                "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]                
}
```

When I test the component(webpack built js) in IE8, I am getting

***Error: Expected Identifier***

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  var REACT_ELEMENT_TYPE = (typeof Symbol === 'function' &&
    Symbol.for && //$$ -> Debugger points here
    Symbol.for('react.element')) ||
    0xeac7;
```

I have included babel-polyfill in my **index.js**

```
import 'babel-polyfill';

//append component to 'div'
```

**Edited**

The file that I have mentioned above is packed using webpack. Should I manually make the change as:

```
Symbol["for"]
```

If I apply production configuration, I am getting the same error but in the following line.

```
e.n=function(t){var n=t&&t.__esModule?function(){return t.default}:function(){return t};
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace `Symbol.for` with `typeof Symbol.for === 'function'`

Answer (score -1):

IE8 does not support [reserved keywords](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords) as property names in dot notation. Use brackets instead

```
Symbol["for"] && //$$ -> Debugger points here
Symbol["for"]('react.element')) ||
```

Comment: `default` is also a reserved word, please take a look at the link I've included.

Comment: I understand that the issue is due to reserved keywords. If you look at my question, I have included **"transform-es3-member-expression-literals", "transform-es3-property-literals"** in babelrc. Is there any other plugins that will take care of this action. i.e default -> "default"

Comment: This answer does not address the question. OP's code sample is generated, not authored; he wants to find out how to generate something that works in IE8.